# The day counter does not update

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following problem. I have two Views. ProgressCardView and BottomSheetView. My goal is to make sure that when you click on the EndSession button in the BottomSheetView, the value changes to +1 in the ProgressCardView, namely the day is increased by +1.

**The problem is that the data does not change when you click on the button.**

Here is my code. My code in the ProgressCardView.

```
struct ProgressCardView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: ProgressSettings

    @State private var daysCount = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                
                HStack {
                    Text(" \(settings.dayCount) / 30 Days")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
                        .italic()
                    Spacer()

                    Text("")
                        .padding(.trailing)
                }
                
                Text("Keep going! You're almost there.")
                    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .regular))
                    .foregroundColor(Color("grey"))
                VStack {
                    ProgressView(value: 0.2)
                        .padding(.top)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                }
                .tint(Color("yellow"))
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: 320)

        .padding()
        .background(Color("backgroundLightSecond"))
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding()

    }
    
    struct ProgressCardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ProgressCardView()
                .environmentObject(ProgressSettings())

        }
    }
}
```

My code in BottomSheetView

```
struct BottomSheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @StateObject var settings = ProgressSettings()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("background")
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Congratulations!")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .medium))
                        .italic()
                    Spacer()
                    Text("")
                        .padding()
                }
                Text("Congratulations on the successful completion of today's exercise. I'll see you tomorrow. You did great! See you tomorrow!")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .regular))
                    .foregroundColor(Color("grey"))
                    .lineSpacing(5)
                
                Divider()
                    .overlay(Color("grey"))

                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()

                        Button(action: {
                            settings.dayCount += 1
                            dismiss()
                        }) {
                            Spacer()

                            Text("End Session")
                                .frame(width: 230)
                                .padding()
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
                                .italic()
                                .background(Color("red"))
                                .cornerRadius(20)
                                .padding()
                            Spacer()

                        }
                        

                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    struct BottomSheetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            BottomSheetView()
                .environmentObject(ProgressSettings())

        }
    }
}
```

and ProgressSettings

```
class ProgressSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dayCount = 0
}
```

Comment: You have an @EnvironmentObject `settings` in `ProgressCardView ` and a new, **different** instance `settings` in `BottomSheetView`. This is likely the issue.

Comment: I agree, if it is an EnvironmentObject then it should be used as such everywhere.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views) how to use `EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: @vadian I tried it, but nothing changed. Can you show me exactly what needs to be changed in the code? Maybe I've done something wrong

Comment: @Joannes I'm use this tutorial but it doesn't work for me

Comment: @MaksimElmers The tutorial is pretty simple and clear. Check `.environmentObject(settings)` in your parent view. Then call it in your child view with `@EnvironmentObject var settings` and not `@StateObject var settings` because  it gets a new instance of `settings`.

Comment: It's unclear where the environment object is initialized and how the views are related to each other in terms of view hierarchy.

Comment: Do not include the tags in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the issue appears to be because you're injecting `ProgressSettings` as an `@EnvironmentObject`, but you're using a newly instantiated `@StateObject` value in `BottomSheetView`.

You need to make sure you're using the same instance everywhere you want this state to be shared.

For example, use an `@EnvironmentObject` in `BottomSheetView`, and make sure the instance is the same as the `ProgressCardView`.

```swift
struct BottomSheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: ProgressSettings

    // ...
}
```

Injecting the instance once in the root of the app ensures there's only a single instance that will be shared across all child views.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var settings = ProgressSettings()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(settings)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already done it and it works. Thanks Bradley